# How to use a while loop to build a stringarray and use it as a list

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app for fellow students, and I am parsing information from a website. I paid a guy to write the parser but did a poor job and he wants more money to help anymore. So im trying to fix it myself.

There is the extractor that grabs the xml info, how the gentlemen had it, was he called it in the main.java like this.

```
      Content1 = extractor.BusRoutes.get(1);
      Content2 = extractor.BusRoutes.get(2);
      Content3 = extractor.BusRoutes.get(3);
```

But there is 30+ buses, and to me, that is not a solid idea. So I tried to do a while loop and an array in order to build the list and make it a list in android.

```
 public class BusRoutes extends ListActivity   {

TransitXMLExtractor extractor;


public String[] busroutearray()
{
    extractor = new TransitXMLExtractor();
    String[] busroutearray = new String[40];    
    int n = 0;
    while(n != (busroutearray.length - 1)){
    busroutearray[n] = extractor.BusRoutes.get(n);
    n++;
}
return busroutearray;
}








/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, busroutearray()));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

bus when i launch it, i always get a forced quit.

edit, the n++ was there before, but got deleted while changing up the code, but with the n++ it still has same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment your counter (n). So the code for the loop would be:

```
while (n != (busroutearray.length - 1)) {
    busroutearray[n] = extractor.BusRoutes.get(n);
    n++;
}
```

Better in this case would be a for loop (a bit easier to read and ideal when you just want to iterate through :

```
for (int i = 0; n < busroutearray.length; i++) {
    busroutearray[i] = extractor.BusRoutes.get(i);
}
```

You might also want to explore using different data structures that are a bit more flexible than arrays ([example](http://www.informatics.susx.ac.uk/courses/dats/notes/html/notes.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your while loop. It is running an infinite while loop because you doesn't change "n" value.

```
    public String[] busroutearray()
    {
        extractor = new TransitXMLExtractor();
        String[] busroutearray = new String[40];    
        int n = 0;

        for (int n = 0; n < busroutearray.length; n++){
           busroutearray[n] = extractor.BusRoutes.get(n);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not incrementing `n`, it's an infinite loop. And Android prolly threw a ANR (Application not Responding).

```
int n = 0;
while(n < busroutearray.length){
    busroutearray[n] = extractor.BusRoutes.get(n);
    n++;
}
```

Though i'm not sure, I think `BusRoutes` is Some kind of `List` of `String`

Why don't you use,

```
String[] busroutearray = extractor.BusRoutes.toArray(new String[extractor.BusRoutes.size()]);
```